# VS2019 macro automation with Visual Commander fails using Edit.GotoBrace command

Tags: macros, visual-studio-2019

I have a brand new laptop running Windows 10pro 64bit.

I just installed the latest version of VS2019 to do some C++ development.

I added to this the [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension so I can make some macros.  I have been trying to use the

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GotoBrace")
```

command, and all it does is spit out the following error.

[image]

I tried just recording it using the temporary macro, but nothing gets recorded when pressing Ctrl+] during the recording phase. I also tried adding the *Edit.GotoBrace* option to the menu directly and recording that, but that doesn't record anything either.

I tried using *Edit.GotoBraceExtend* as well, but I got the same results.

Has something changed drastically with this command and/or am I doing something wrong?  You can reproduce this simply by editing the temporary macro and pasting the line into it, saving, compiling and running it on a document where you have some braces or parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this command from the VCmd menu or a keyboard shortcut when the target document is the active window. (Otherwise the command will be executed for a Visual Commander window that doesn't support it).

Comment: I assigned a keyboard shortcut to it and that worked.  If I have a source file open and I just click Run for the selected command in the Commands list, it gives the error. Thank you for the info.  I intended to use a keyboard shortcut anyway, so this works for me.